# Ejecutar .BAT desde .NET

Tags: vb.net, .net, batch

Lo que quiero es lo siguiente ,tengo el siguiente .BAT

```
color 30
cls
@echo off
echo.
echo.
echo DIGITE LA IP DE LA IMPRESORA QUE DESEA CONFIGURAR Y PRESIONE "ENTER":
set /P IP=
echo DIGITE EL NOMBRE DE LA IMPRESORA Y PRESIONE "ENTER", EJEMPLO:IBMDE11BLM1

 set /P NOMBRE=

cscript %windir%\SysWOW64\Printing_Admin_Scripts\es-ES\prnport.vbs -a -r %IP% -h %IP% -o  raw -n 9100 -me
pause
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "%NOMBRE%" /f "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\lmud1p40.inf_amd64_9a2338ab5b59d9ef\lmud1p40.inf" /r %IP% /m "Lexmark Universal v2 XL" /u
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%NOMBRE%"
rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /e /n "%NOMBRE%"
echo SE INSTALO CORRECTAMENTE "ENTER" 
pause
exit
```

Lo que quiero es en .NET mediante la llamada de un  boton invocarlo y pasarle los parametros de ip y nombre mediante el TextBox1.text y el TextBox2.text

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Shell("C:\Users\carvajal\Desktop\Autoinstalar Impresora V 0.3.bat").
    vbNormalFocus).
End Sub
```

Porque puedo invocar el .BAT mediante shell pero como le paso esos parametros ,alquien me puede dar una pista ,he visto que es mediante un %1 y %2 no veo ejemplo de ello para lograrlo, o si es posible desde el mismo .net crear mi propio .BAT y ejecutar las ordenes.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que utilizar [Process.Start](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2) y luego leer el stream de salida con [standardoutput](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Te puedes ayudar este articulo que lo escribí en el 2007 (si bien esta en ASP.NET 2.0 y VB)

- Capturar salida de un proceso: Ejemplo comandos básicos (ping, tracert, cmd /?, etc)
  https://geeks.ms/fernandezja/2007/09/11/capturar-salida-de-un-proceso-ejemplo-comandos-bsicos-ping-tracert-cmd-etc/

Algo asi

```
      Dim p As Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo)

      'Leemos la salida (objeto StreamReader)
      Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = p.StandardOutput
      Dim cadenaSalida As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
      sr.Close()
```

y tienes en la cadenaSalida lo que necesitas

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.